In shapes I only want to apply backgrond color to a specific text/words not the entire line
I've a code which updates the data in shapes based on 2 conditions-
if a line starts with "(" it looks for column 2 in Excel, find same match and update/add the column 3 and 5 text in shape.
if a line doesn't start with "(" it looks for column 3 in Excel, find same match and update/add column 2 and 5 in shape.
The font and background color are taken from column 3 and 4 to apply to the relevant text in shapes.
Everything works well, but just the background color is getting added in whole line but I want it to applied only on the word we extracted/added.
You'll understand if you review the code. It would be great if someone has a solution for this.
    Sub UpdateShapesFromExcel()
        Dim doc As Document
        Dim shape As shape
        Dim line As String
        Dim updatedLine As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim partNum As String
        Dim desc As String
        Dim partNumExcel As String
        Dim descExcel As String
        Dim additionalText As String
        Dim partNumFound As Boolean
        Dim descFound As Boolean
        Dim cleanedPartNum As String
        Dim cleanedDesc As String
        Dim cleanedDescExcel As String
        Dim cleanedPartNumExcel As String
        Dim xlApp As Object
        Dim wb As Object
        Dim ws As Object
        Dim fontColor As Long
        Dim bgColor As Long
        Dim additionalTextFontColor As Long
        Dim additionalTextBgColor As Long
        Dim fileDialog As fileDialog
        Dim excelFilePath As String

        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        Set fileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        With fileDialog
            .Title = "Select the Excel file"
            .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm", 1
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
            excelFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With

        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlApp.Visible = False
        Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

        If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Set doc = ActiveDocument
        If doc.Shapes.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

        For Each shape In doc.Shapes
            If Not shape.TextFrame Is Nothing Then
                If shape.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    For i = 1 To shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count
                        line = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(i).Range.text
                        updatedLine = line
                        partNumFound = False
                        descFound = False
                        line = CleanString(line)
                        If Left(line, 1) = "(" Then
                            partNum = Mid(line, 2, InStr(2, line, ")") - 2)
                            cleanedPartNum = CleanString(partNum)
                            For j = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                                partNumExcel = ws.Cells(j, 2).Value
                                cleanedPartNumExcel = CleanString(partNumExcel)
                                If UCase(cleanedPartNum) = UCase(cleanedPartNumExcel) Then
                                    desc = ws.Cells(j, 3).Value
                                    additionalText = ws.Cells(j, 5).Value
                                    fontColor = ws.Cells(j, 3).Font.Color
                                    bgColor = ws.Cells(j, 3).Interior.Color
                                    updatedLine = "(" & cleanedPartNum & ") " & desc
                                    If Len(additionalText) > 0 Then
                                        updatedLine = updatedLine & vbCrLf & additionalText & vbCrLf
                                        additionalTextFontColor = ws.Cells(j, 5).Font.Color
                                        additionalTextBgColor = ws.Cells(j, 5).Interior.Color
                                    Else
                                        updatedLine = updatedLine & vbCrLf
                                    End If
                                    partNumFound = True
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next j
                        Else
                            desc = Trim(line)
                            cleanedDesc = CleanString(desc)
                            For j = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                                descExcel = ws.Cells(j, 3).Value
                                cleanedDescExcel = CleanString(descExcel)
                                If UCase(Trim(cleanedDesc)) = UCase(Trim(cleanedDescExcel)) Then
                                    partNum = ws.Cells(j, 2).Value
                                    additionalText = ws.Cells(j, 5).Value
                                    fontColor = ws.Cells(j, 3).Font.Color
                                    bgColor = ws.Cells(j, 3).Interior.Color
                                    updatedLine = "(" & partNum & ") " & cleanedDesc
                                    If Len(additionalText) > 0 Then
                                        updatedLine = updatedLine & vbCrLf & additionalText & vbCrLf
                                        additionalTextFontColor = ws.Cells(j, 5).Font.Color
                                        additionalTextBgColor = ws.Cells(j, 5).Interior.Color
                                    Else
                                        updatedLine = updatedLine & vbCrLf
                                    End If
                                    descFound = True
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next j
                        End If

                        ' Now apply font and background color to the updated line (part number or description)
                        If partNumFound Or descFound Then
                            ' Apply font and background color for part number or description (not additional text)
                            With shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(i).Range
                                .text = updatedLine
                                .Font.Color = fontColor
                                .ParagraphFormat.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = bgColor
                            End With

                            ' Now apply font and background color ONLY for additional text (column 5)
                            If Len(additionalText) > 0 Then
                                ' Apply additional text formatting ONLY to the additional text (if it's a description)
                                If descFound Then
                                    ' Apply formatting to the next paragraph (i+1) for additional text.
                                    With shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(i + 1).Range
                                        .Font.Color = additionalTextFontColor
                                        .ParagraphFormat.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = additionalTextBgColor
                                    End With
                                Else
                                    ' For part number, apply formatting to the next paragraph (i+1) for additional text.
                                    With shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(i + 1).Range
                                        .Font.Color = additionalTextFontColor
                                        .ParagraphFormat.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = additionalTextBgColor
                                    End With
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next i
                End If
            End If
        Next shape

        wb.Close False
        xlApp.Quit
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Set wb = Nothing
        Set ws = Nothing
        Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler:
        ' Handle errors here if needed.
    End Sub

    Function CleanString(s As String) As String
        s = Trim(s)
        s = Replace(s, Chr(160), " ")
        s = Replace(s, vbTab, " ")
        s = Replace(s, vbCrLf, " ")
        s = Replace(s, vbCr, " ")
        s = Replace(s, vbLf, " ")
        CleanString = s
    End Function


FYI when you use For i = 1 To shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count the Count property is evaluated at the start of the loop and does not get re-evaluated, so if you add paragraphs to the shape inside the loop, you may end up missing paragraphs at the end...

Here's a basic example of how to format specific text in a shape:
Sub Tester()
    Dim tf As TextFrame, p As Paragraph, txt
    
    Set tf = ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame
    HighlightTextInRange tf.TextRange, "this", vbGreen, vbRed
    
End Sub

Sub HighlightTextInRange(rng As Range, txt As String, _
                         textColor As Long, shadeColor As Long)
    Dim pos, c As Long, f As Range
    pos = InStr(1, rng.Text, txt, vbTextCompare)
    Do While pos > 0
        Set f = rng.Duplicate
        f.SetRange pos - 1, pos + Len(txt) - 1
        f.Font.Color = textColor
        f.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = shadeColor
        pos = InStr(pos + 1, rng.Text, txt, vbTextCompare)
    Loop
End Sub

Result:

